# ~ machen die Goldbären zu einem ganz besonders

Tags: meaning, verb

This is from the HARIBO jelly bag.

> sorgfältig ausgewählte Zutaten und eine seit mehr als 90 Jahren ständig verbesserte Rezeptur machen die Goldbären zu einem ganz besonders einzigartigen Vergnügen.

This translates to (by [deepl.com](https://www.deepl.com/translator))

> carefully selected ingredients and a recipe that has been continuously improved for more than 90 years make the Gold Bears a particularly unique pleasure.

In `... machen die Goldbären zu einem ganz ...` Why is there `zu einem ...` Why isn't it just `...machen die Goldbären ein ganz besonders ..`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> … machen die Goldbären zu einem (…) Vergnügen.

This is tricky because *zu etwas machen* is a special phrase meaning *to turn into*. So, it's not the Goldbären who are acting, but the ingredients, and the Goldbären are acted upon.

> … machen die Goldbären ein (…) Vergnügen.

Here, the Goldbären are acting, but that's not what the author wanted to say.

The deepl.com translation is right on the spot. English also makes that distinction by putting the verb *make* in front ob *the Gold bears* instead of behind it, so SPO word order makes it clear *the Gold bears* are an object. In German, word order isn't sufficient to mark the object.

Comment: I see. In English it's just `make A B` or `turn A into B` but in German it's `make A to B`.

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

The sentence from the bag:

> Sorgfältig ausgewählte Zutaten und eine seit mehr als 90 Jahren ständig verbesserte Rezeptur machen die Goldbären zu einem ganz besonders einzigartigen Vergnügen.

The machine translation by deepl.com is adequate.

Reduced to the basic structure, we get:

> X machen Y zu Z.
>   [Die Zutaten] machen [die Goldbären] zu [einem Erlebnis].

Reducing it further, we get the verb:

> etwas zu etwas machen.
>   to make sth. into sth.

And in this structure, we cannot omit the *zu*.
There are more examples of this at [*pons* online](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=etwas%2Bzu%2Betwas%2Bmachen&l=deen&in=&lf=de#).

Comment: Thanks now I can understand it. I chose the other answer just because it mentioned about `machen A B`(where B is a verb). But your answer is just as good.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help.